# VT-x doesn't work after enabled in the BIOS

Tags: bios

I enable it through BIOS, but sysinfo still says it's not enabled any help?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: That doesn't refer to the physical CPU of your system. That refers to the *virtual* CPU you created in VBox.

Comment: Can you install and run a 64-bit Guest? If so, Hardware Virtualization has been enabled in machine BIOS.

Comment: Home come? I can't change no settings without VT-x enabled https://imgur.com/a/G3PjSqP

Comment: Nope, this is my first VM on this PC @John

Comment: So the second message says virtualization isn't enabled in the host, and advises to disable it in the VM:s system settings to start it - did you try that?

Comment: Check the hardware virtualization settings in machine BIOS and make sure all have been enabled (usually 2 settings)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If my comment and and link Ramhound posted for you do not work, your machine may not support hardware virtualization.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/PbAZ3N8.jpg https://i.imgur.com/3n6jrhZ.png I have both enabled, and it still doesn't work. I need this for my VM only so I don't really know how to put up my question

Comment: @an9xia - Follow the instructions in the duplicate’s answer. Your error is due to Hyper-V being installed more than likely. Relevant information contained in your comments should instead be an [edit] to your question. Looking at the build of Windows your using it most definitely due to the fact you have Hyper-V installed.  Update to 21H1.  Verify you are running the current supported version of VirtualBox

Comment: I tried the guide above, it didn't work. I'm using VM Version 6.1.26 r145957 (Qt5.6.2) and Windows 20H2, I guess I'll try updating my Windows now. @Ramhound

Comment: @an9xia - Is that System Information from within a guest OS or the host OS?

Comment: Host OS. @Ramhound

Comment: Use your phone to screenshot the BIOS options that you have enabled and add this to your post.

Comment: ^ I already did https://i.imgur.com/PbAZ3N8.jpg - @harrymc

Comment: Try to switch off "core isolation" in *Windows Security > Device security*.

Comment: @an9xia - Easily missed since your not editing your question like your supposed to

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/3Ipx4Lv.png, no luck here either .. @harrymc

Comment: @an9xia - Try Uninstalling Hyper-V be sure you have zero applications other than VirtualBox that requires VT-x installed.  Sadly only you can determine what applications you have installed on your system

Comment: There is a newer [BIOS version F10b](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-H61M-S1-rev-20/support#support-dl-bios). Which revision is your GA-H61M-S1 motherboard?

Answer (score -1):

You can't have Hyper-V and VirtualBox enabled at the same time and run your VM in VirtualBox with hardware acceleration (VT-x). A 32-bit guest OS will run painfully slow, and a 64-bit guest OS will not run at all.

If you have already created a 64-bit VM in VirtualBox before you enabled Hyper-V in Windows, you won't be able to run it now, and this is why you're seeing the error message in VirtualBox.

If you are trying to create a new 64-bit VM while Hyper-V is enabled, VirtualBox will not allow it and display a warning message, like the one you see in the linked duplicate question.

I see from the comments in the other question that VirtualBox now supports Hyper-V. I have done some research into this and it appears that VirtualBox 6.0 and higher versions do support Hyper-V, but as it's indicated in [the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/en/virtualization/virtualbox/6.0/admin/hyperv-support.html), this is an experimental feature. So if you're trying to create a new 64-bit VM while Hyper-V is enabled, you will need to enable the [Windows Hypervisor Platform](https://us.informatiweb.net/tutorials/it/virtualization/virtualbox-use-virtualbox-and-hyper-v-at-the-same-time.html). Do note that it will run painfully slow. If however you already have an existing VM that you created earlier, then additional steps may be required to make it take advantage of this new experimental support for Hyper-V, probably from the command line, using VBoxManage.